# Can armature/bones be edited without edit mode?

Tags: scripting, bones

I was looking after some information about armature and bones, so I can continue my importer script. I found some nice info [here](https://github.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender/blob/master/object_convert_to_armature.py); no BMesh, and simple enough for my needs as beginner, so just perfect. But while looking at the code I saw that it uses "edit mode" (line 120), what I wanted to avoid.

So my question is: can I programmatically add/manipulate bones, without edit mode? Is there any better way then in [this](https://github.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender/blob/master/object_convert_to_armature.py) code?

I also tried to use the "bones" collection, but I could not append/new/add items into them.

Comment: Learn more about armature by reading Rigify addon scripts. I recommend _init_.py and generate.py for starter. 
Also, as @Adhi mentioned, you must be in edit mode to add or remove bones.

Comment: I have to say the "edit mode" requirement annoys me.  I have a philosophy that all operations should be possible in python without using anything from bpy.ops or fiddling with the editor state.  In practice, developers have limited time and some operations are just unreasonable (like unlinking an object from the scene while the user is in edit mode).  Still, I think those principles are a good goal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, The armature must be in Edit mode for us to be allowed to add or remove bones. We can switch into and out of it, using [`bpy.ops.object.mode_set`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.mode_set). An idiom I use a couple of times in my [addon](https://github.com/adhihargo/rigging_tools/blob/master/rigging_tools.py), is to store initial mode in a variable (`prev_mode`), then restore it when I'm finished:

```
prev_mode = armature.mode # save

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
for bone in context.selected_bones:
    # do anything in edit mode
    hook_name = PRF_HOOK + bone.name
    hook = armature.data.edit_bones.new(hook_name)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
for bone in context.selected_pose_bones:
    # do anything in pose mode
    hook = armature.pose.bones[PRF_HOOK + bone_name]
    ct_constraint = hook.constraints.new('COPY_TRANSFORMS')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=prev_mode) # restore
```

This way, we can access any editing mode, any number of times, without the user even notice when the script is finished.

Comment: This snippet: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Armatures seems to favour `bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()`. Maybe it's something new, or maybe it's not a good idea in case it's already edit mode? In any case I haven't tested it.