# Move rig bones positions with shape key

Tags: rigging, armature, shape-keys

I am making a character that morphs using a shape key, is it possible to re-position the bones and add them to the shape key of the character morph? I have looked at drivers but they do the exact opposite of what I desire. Essential what i want to do is make the rigs bones larger as it transforms.

Comment: Your interesting question is a very unusual approach. What are you trying to do exactly? In CG every problem can be solved in many different ways, probably you can reach your goal in a simpler way. Anyway bones attributes can be modified by drivers, but only in pose mode, not in edit mode.

Comment: @joshsanfelici I have a person, and i animate him into a larger, more exotic creature using a shape key, However the bones do not move, they still have the same position as the original model, and when i try to animate the new morphed character in the editor his bones do not effect the correct space. I used automatic weights to apply the rig, if that makes a difference.

Comment: If it were my own project, i would build two different armatures, one for the "normal" and one for the "exotic" creature. Could it be an interesting approach for your project?

Comment: @joshsanfelici The guy is doing a walk cycle as he transforms into the exotic being, I just need to make the rig bigger, without actually distorting the creature. So from frame 1 - 30 he transforms, but I want the rig to also transform from frame 1-30. While I understand i can apply multiple rigs to the same mesh, If I go on to make another 3 massive morphs transforms, that's another 3 rigs. Being able to animate the rig transforming would be preferred.

Comment: I think I have a solution, but cannot try until tomorrow, But I think I have to build the mesh to the same proportions as my original and then resize the 'exotic' version using the scaling of the bones in Pose mode. Which kind of makes sense now. (I will google the driver thing tomorrow also @joshsanfelici because I had only found information relating to shape keys and drivers)

Comment: If the morphing is proportional it should be esiaer to manage, but consider that a bone controls lots of vertices and you want many vertices to control the bones: I think that an armature going from frame 1 to 15 and the second "exotic" from 16 to 30 would get the job done, with the help of dedicated shape keys, better if driven. Consider that you can copy an armature and resize/modify it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I don't understand the question ;/.

Comment: @joshsanfelici after doing some research and thinking outside the box I came across a question here [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/can-armature-bones-be-edited-without-edit-mode) that asks how to move the bones without edit mode with python script, however the answer given was what i required, moving the bone in edit mode with python, This is essentially what I want to do, but is alot of work if I would only use it once,

Comment: But this led me to googling 'blender drivers moving bones in edit mode' which came up with this [link](https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-247429.html) and describes the exact actions I am trying to undertake, At the very end Pesho describes how to do the reverse of what most people use drivers for, So Shapekeys moving bones... So my theory of action at the moment is to setup a bone with drivers to change the shapekey, and while that shapekey is changing another driver is changing the bone positions. So I will test this out and see if this does exactly what I want.

Comment: Let me know if it was successfully!